# Wordpress - enqueue js issue - page broken, no error

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to migrate a theme to Wordpress.
As usual, I imported all CSS, and now I'm moving on to the JS portion.

This is how my function.php looks:

```
    <?php

function greennectar_files() {
  
// enqueue CSS

  wp_enqueue_style('custom-google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Roboto:100,300,400,400i,700,700i');
  wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('university_main_styles', get_stylesheet_uri());
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapcss',   get_theme_file_uri('/css/bootstrap.css'), null, array(), );
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap8',  get_theme_file_uri('/vendors/linericon/style.css'), null, array(), );
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap4',  get_theme_file_uri('/css/font-awesome.min.css'), null, array(), );
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap2',  get_theme_file_uri('/vendors/nice-select/css/nice-select.css'), null, array(), );
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap3',  get_theme_file_uri('/vendors/animate-css/animate.css'), null, array(), );
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap5',  get_theme_file_uri('/css/animate.min.css'), null, array(), );
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap6',  get_theme_file_uri('/vendors/flaticon/flaticon.css'), null, array(), );


// enqueue JAVASCRIPT



    wp_enqueue_script('popper',             get_theme_file_uri('/js/popper.js'), array('jquery') , array(), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_theme_file_uri('/js/bootstrap.min.js'), array('popper'), array(), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js4', get_theme_file_uri('/js/stellar.js'), array('bootstrap'), array(), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js5', get_theme_file_uri('/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js'), array('bootstrap'), array(), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js6', get_theme_file_uri('/vendors/nice-select/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js'), array('bootstrap'), array(), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js7', get_theme_file_uri('/vendors/isotope/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js'), array('bootstrap'), array(), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js8', get_theme_file_uri('/vendors/isotope/isotope-min.js'), array('bootstrap'), array(), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js9', get_theme_file_uri('/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js'), array('bootstrap'), array(), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js10', get_theme_file_uri('/js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js'), array('bootstrap'), array(), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js11', get_theme_file_uri('/js/mail-script.js'), array('bootstrap'), array(), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js12', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCjCGmQ0Uq4exrzdcL6rvxywDDOvfAu6eE', NULL, false, true);
  wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js13', get_theme_file_uri('/js/gmaps.min.js'), NULL, array(), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js14', get_theme_file_uri('/js/theme.js'), NULL, array(), true);
  
}

// THEME FUNCTIONS

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'greennectar_files');

function greennectar_features() {
  add_theme_support('title-tag');
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
    )
  );
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'greennectar_features');
```

And this is how the original HTML theme does it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <title>Steve Portfolio</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/linericon/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/nice-select/css/nice-select.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/animate-css/animate.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/flaticon/flaticon.css" />
    <!-- main css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/stellar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/nice-select/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/isotope/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/isotope/isotope-min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mail-script.js"></script>
    <!--gmaps Js-->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCjCGmQ0Uq4exrzdcL6rvxywDDOvfAu6eE"></script>
    <script src="js/gmaps.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/theme.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The original version (second one) works fine with the HTML. Mine is very very twitchy. Half the scripts seem not to load.

What I tried:

1. I tried making sure I load the scripts based on what is recommended in the second one:
2. Tried deregistering WordPress jQuery and adding the new 3.2.1 version, did not help.
3. Tried moving the scripts proposed in step 1 to the top of the page.
4. Tried adding jquery as a dependency to all of the scripts.

Neither of these helped. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) expects an *array* of strings, not a string, for the `$deps` parameter.

So, for example, your code should read:

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'popper', get_theme_file_uri('/js/popper.js'), array( 'jquery' ), array(), true );
```